# Cobertura report is not generating when java version is changed from java 6 to 8

Tags: java, ecobertura

In my ant build.xml am using cobertra-2.1 jar and asm 5 jar Testng files executed successfully but report is not generating meanwhile instrumented folder also not generating.

Tried with different versions of jars asm-4.1 and asm 5 and cobertura upgraded versions also.

Comment: Unless something changed since I last checked, and it would seem it didn't, [cobertura does not work with java 8](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/176). You can check out [JaCoCo](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/) as an alternative

Comment: That depends on your issue. StackOverflow is not a "rent a coder" site, it's just a community of people allocating some of their time to help others. So first you need to try yourself, and then post a question if you're having problems

Comment: No actually my client prefering only Cobertura we won't go with JaCoCo

Comment: Good luck then :)

Comment: finally we resolved the issue after we changed asm jar version from 4.1 to 6 , report generated successfully.

Comment: Cool, does it work with lambdas/method references as well?

Comment: for lamdas/method references didn't checked..for us cobertura report is generated fine.